# React Native Expo Failed building JavaScript bundle

Tags: react-native, expo

After installing a package and running react-native link. I get the following error message in the logs of exp start when I try to launch the simulator on Xcode:

> Failed building JavaScript bundle.

There's 0 additional information and my project runs but this errors show up in the terminal and the get the simulator stuck at 0%...

I have no idea how to fix this since I'm unable to get any additional error nor information, just this ****** error message.

Comment: I think it's a cache problem. try "rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*"

Comment: @MarouenMhiri Thank you whoever you are you're the angel of my day. You saved me seriously I was in the process of remaking a new expo detach project and then I would have had to rewrite all my code etc... Anyways THANK YOU

Comment: Just a minor typo tho it's "rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*" for anyone reading this later on.

Comment: glad this could help! and thx for the -rf :-)

Comment: How to resolve this issue on windows? the `rm` command doesn't work on windows. Should we also need to clear Expo cache list in android phone (expo app list)?

Comment: `exp start -c` will work today (to clear cache)

Comment: I had same problem now but i solved by `pressing R` in command prompt - hope this help to someone.

Comment: There are some suggestions for debugging this at at https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15841 but no really good fix

Answer (score 3):

Clearing the cache via `expo start -c` AND restarting the bundler by pressing R in the terminal as Hameed suggested helped in my case

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to start an app on the Android emulator.  Changing the connection mode to tunnel from LAN on the server console allowed the app to build.